# Trying to display PostGIS data with Leaflet through a GeoJSON API

Tags: postgis, leaflet, geojson

I build a little GeoJSON-API in node.js, express and node-postgres.
The data (points and multilines) comes from a PostGIS DB.
I query data in JavaScript through the customized function "rowjsonb_to_geojson" from [Paul Ramsey´s blog](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/03/geojson.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rowjsonb_to_geojson(
  rowjsonb JSONB, 
  geom_column TEXT DEFAULT 'geom')
RETURNS json AS 
$$
DECLARE 
 json_props jsonb;
 json_geom jsonb;
 json_type jsonb;
BEGIN
 IF NOT rowjsonb ? geom_column THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'geometry column ''%'' is missing', geom_column;
 END IF;
 json_geom := ST_AsGeoJSON((rowjsonb ->> geom_column)::geometry)::jsonb;
 json_geom := jsonb_build_object('geometry', json_geom);
 json_props := jsonb_build_object('properties', rowjsonb - geom_column);
 json_type := jsonb_build_object('type', 'Feature');
 return (json_type || json_geom || json_props)::text;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

My express get request is:

```
app.get("/standorts", async(request, response) => {
    try {
        const queryStandortFC = "SELECT 'FeatureCollection' as type, 'standorts' as name, json_build_object('type', 'name', 'properties', json_build_object('name', 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84')) AS CRS, array_to_json(array_agg(rowjsonb_to_geojson(to_jsonb(standort.*)))) AS FEATURES FROM standort";
        const getAllStandorts = await pool.query(queryStandortFC);
        response.json(getAllStandorts.rows[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }
});
```

(the 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84' I took from a manual export of the data with QGIS)

The delivered data looks good, at least I think so:

```
 {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "standorts",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          711646.5,
          5294041
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "5",
        "nr": "002"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          711989.5,
          5293268
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "6",
        "nr": "003"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          712194.5,
          5292960
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "7",
        "nr": "004"
      }
    }
```

I try to display the data from the API with Leaflet:

```
// empty Leaflet-Layer for api points
let pointsLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mymap); 
//fetch the data from the api --> Only 2 Layers from DB Points, Lines
fetchApiData("http://localhost:3003/standorts", standObj, pointsLayer)

function fetchApiData(jsonUrl, jsonVar, layerVar) {
    linesObj = {};
    standObj = {};
    fetch(jsonUrl, { method: "GET", mode: "cors" })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => jsonVar = data)
        .then(jsonVar => console.log(jsonUrl, " data: ", jsonVar))
        .then(jsonVar => putUpStuff(jsonUrl, jsonVar, layerVar))
        .catch(console.error)
};

// use the data and put it into a JSONlayer for leaflet
async function putUpStuff(filename, data, jsonLayer) {
    try {
        await jsonLayer.addData(data)
        console.log("putUpStuff: ", filename, " --> ", data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("putUpStuff: The data does not work -->", filename, ", data: ", data)
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}
```

The function fetchApiData gets the data from the PostGIS database and also console.logs it.

The function putUpStuff catches the error
`putUpStuff: The data does not work --> http://localhost:3003/lines , data:  undefined`
and gives me back the error message:
`Cannot read property 'features' of undefined`

Does anyone know a solution on how else I can fetch GeoJSON from an API and display it with Leaflet?

Comment: Two problems: (1) GeoJSON coordinates must be lat-long (EPSG:4326). You seem to be getting UTM-projected coordinates. (2) the return value of `console.log()` is `undefined`, so when you're doing `.then(jsonVar => console.log(jsonUrl, " data: ", jsonVar))` and then reusing names of variables, you're losing the data.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot alter the basedata´s crs, but I could change the crs during the rowjsonb_to_geojson query. 
I will try to squeeze a ST_Transform() into the query. 

The fetchApiData is only called two times, once for points (in example) and once for lines (I didn´t include them because of the data mass). 
I didn´t get, why the data is lost. Do I need to change the variables from one promise, to the next?

Comment: The problem you are having with understanding JS `fetch` method is not GIS related, so it's more suited for StackOverflow site.

Comment: re `fetch`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320082/objects-returned-from-promise-are-undefined